# Hbase client reading different user for read and write

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hbase-client

I am using hbase client 2.1.7 to connect to my server(same version 2.1.7).

> ```
>         <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
>         <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
>         <version>2.1.7</version>
> ```

Now there is an user who have permission to read/write on the table in the server.

User = LTzm@yA$U

For this my code looks like this:

```
String hadoop_user_key = "HADOOP_USER_NAME"; 
String user = "LTzm@yA$U";
System.setProperty(hadoop_user_key, token);
```

Now when I am trying to read the key from the table i am getting following error:

> error.log:! Causing:
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient
> permissions for user 'LTzm' (table=table_name, action=READ)

Weird part is writes are working fine. To validate that whether right user is getting passed for write, i removed the user and try rerun the code and the write fails with the error:

> error.log:! org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient
> permissions (user=LTzm@yA$U,
> scope=table_name, family=d:visitId,
> params=[table=table_name,family=d:visitId],action=WRITE)

Again read was also failing with:

> error.log:! org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient
> permissions for user 'LTzm'
> (table=table_name, action=READ)

Somehow Ltzm is getting passed with read call and LTzm@yA$U is getting passed for write.
Does anyone help me what is the issue here, Is @ or special symbol not allowed in the user for hbase(then how is it working for write calls).

Edit 1:
Here is the function to create connection:

> ```
>     public static Connection createConnection() {
>             String hadoop_user_key = "HADOOP_USER_NAME"; 
>             String user = "LTzm@yA$U";
>
>             Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>();
>             configMap.put("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://session/apps/hbase/data"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "ip1, ip2");
>             configMap.put("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase");
>             configMap.put("hbase.rpc.timeout", "400");
>             configMap.put("hbase.rpc.shortoperation.timeout", "400");
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.meta.operation.timeout", "5000");
>             configMap.put("hbase.rpc.engine", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine");
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.retries.number", "3");
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.operation.timeout", "3000"));
>             configMap.put(HConstants.HBASE_CLIENT_IPC_POOL_SIZE,  "30"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.pause", "50"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.pause.cqtbe", "1000"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.max.total.tasks", "500"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.max.perserver.tasks", "50"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.max.perregion.tasks", "10"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.ipc.pool.type", "RoundRobinPool");
>             configMap.put("hbase.rpc.read.timeout", "200"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.rpc.write.timeout", "200"));
>             configMap.put("hbase.client.write.buffer", "20971520"));
>
>             System.setProperty(hadoop_user_key, token);
>
>             Configuration hConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
>             for (String key : configMap.keySet())
>                 hConfig.set(key, configMap.get(key));
>
>             UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hConfig);
>
>             Connection hbaseConnection;
>             hbaseConnection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
>
>             return connection;
>
>
>     }
> ```

Here are the read and write calls:

> ```
> protected Result read(String tableName, String rowKey) throws IOException {
>     Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
>     get.addFamily(COLUMN_FAMILY_BYTES);
>
>     Result res;
>     Table hTable = null;
>     try {
>         hTable = getHbaseTable(tableName);
>         res = hTable.get(get);
>     } finally {
>         if (hTable != null) {
>             releaseHbaseTable(hTable);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return res;
> }
>
>
>
> protected void writeRow(String tableName, String rowKey, Map<String, byte[]> columnData) throws IOException {
>     Put cellPut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
>     for (String qualifier : columnData.keySet()) {
>         cellPut.addColumn(COLUMN_FAMILY_BYTES, Bytes.toBytes(qualifier), columnData.get(qualifier));
>     }
>     Table hTable = null;
>     try {
>         hTable = getHbaseTable(tableName);
>         if (hTable != null) {
>             hTable.put(cellPut);
>         }
>     } finally {
>         if (hTable != null) {
>             releaseHbaseTable(hTable);
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>
>
> private Table getTable(String tableName) {
>     try {
>         Table table = hbaseConnection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         LOGGER.error("Exception while adding table in factory.", e);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please show your actual read and write code as a [mcve]

Comment: I'd recommend looking through the HBase source code, but realistically I'd say that you're asking for trouble by having a username like that. Your easiest solution will be to make a new username that doesn't contain special characters.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for reply. We have changed the username without special characters but i wanted to know the reason why is this happening.